# Listing files in directory

Tags: visual-c++

I have created a windows form in c++ which, upon a button click, opens a dialog box for folder selection.

Now what I would like to do is get the list of files in that directory so that I can process them one by one.

I have googled it in many ways, and found many ways which include external libraries (such as boost and diren.h). I would not like to use external resources, but the ones at my disposal, the default ones.

I've read about FindFirstFile and FindNextFile, but couldnt get that combination to work.

Could you please assist?

Thanks a lot,
Idan.

Here is the updated code:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
FolderBrowserDialog^ folderBrowserDialog1 = gcnew FolderBrowserDialog;

if (folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
        String ^ selected = folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath;

        selected += "\\*";

        char* stringPointer = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(selected).ToPointer();

        hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)stringPointer, &FindFileData);
        while(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("Found file: %s\r\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
            if(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) == FALSE)
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: What did you try with FindFirstFile, what did you expect and what did not work?

Comment: I added my code.
Basically I would like to fetch the files names into char * so that I could use them later.

Comment: Well, I understood a part of what you wrote, and in the meanwhile I have found a new approach - please review the updated code. Now, I would like to (using the dialogbox) select a directory into the "selected " variable. Then, I would like to iterate the files in that directory. I'm expecting a char* for each file name, so that I could save them and then use them later on. Thanks again!

Comment: What did you expect and what did not work? Do you get hFind!= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE? Do you find file name as expected?

Comment: yes, I get hFind=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, and therefor the file name is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

You obviously compile for UNICODE (wide char) since you need to cast the newStr for the lpFileName parameter of FindFirstFile. But since you pass an ANSI string, you probable won't get a useful result. Youd didn't write, what you expect to find.

In the code beforer FindFirstFile you manually convert the SelectedPath value to ANSI char. That makes no sense, when you need a wide char string anyway. Get the LPCWSTR from the String selected with the StringToHGlobalUni method. This looks somehow like this (not tested):

```
LPCWSTR stringPointer = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(selected).ToPointer(); 

hFind = FindFirstFile(stringPointer, &FindFileData);
```

In general: Don't use casts except when you need to adapt a bad designed interface. Use it only when you know exactly what you are doing.

Further you don't check the hFind result of FindFirstFile. It will be INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if you pass a pointer to the wrong string format.